# How to convert a query on Bookshelf.js ( alias table )

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I have a complex query:

```
 SELECT *
FROM   `relations` L1
WHERE `minor_from` = 2 and `major_from` = 2  and `type` = "friend" 
       AND  EXISTS
  (

       SELECT * FROM   `relations` L2 WHERE  
       (L1.`minor_from` = L2.`minor_to` AND L1.`major_from` = L2.`major_to` and L1.`minor_from` = L2.`minor_to` AND L1.`major_from` = L2.`major_to`) AND 
       (L2.`minor_from` = L1.`minor_to` AND L2.`major_from` = L1.`major_to` and L2.`minor_from` = L1.`minor_to` AND L2.`major_from` = L1.`major_to`)
)
```

Which gives friends of user.

I am able to add whereRaw in Bookshelf.js but cannot add alias L1 `SELECT * FROM relations L1`

Any idea how to query that.

Edit:

It will be helpful if someone can tell me how to run complete raw query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To mark it as answer:

I used knex.js to do that. I could have and probably will use knex methods but for testing I have this:

```
    knex('relations as L1').where('L1.minor_from', '=',req.body.minor ).where('L1.major_from', '=',req.body.major).where('L1.type', '=', 'friend').whereExists(function() {
                        this.select('*').from('relations as L2').whereRaw(' (L1.`minor_from` = L2.`minor_to` AND L1.`major_from` = L2.`major_to` and L1.`minor_from` = L2.`minor_to` AND L1.`major_from` = L2.`major_to`) AND (L2.`minor_from` = L1.`minor_to` AND L2.`major_from` = L1.`major_to` and L2.`minor_from` = L1.`minor_to` AND L2.`major_from` = L1.`major_to`)');
                }).then(function(collection) { res.json(200, collection);});
```